# Visual Studio Code, one setting for multiple language

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to include CSS in HTML as one line, so lets say if i want to change the tabSize i will only need to do it once for both HTML and CSS

Currently looks like this:

```
"[html]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
},

"[css]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2
}
```

But i want something like this:

```
"[html, css]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

See the end of [file-type specific settings issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1587).  Multiple language keys in one setting are brought up (and earlier in the thread) but it is stated that there are no plans to support that (as of May, 2017).

> So is later support of multiple langauges per key/entry something planned for the future?
>   Is there a sep[a]rate issue to track that?
>
> [Response:] Its not yet planned.. Feel free to file an issue for that. Thanks.